# C++ Pointer to Members

Tags: c++, pointers, member, pointer-to-member

If I have two classes that are in the same hierarchy with a member of the same name and type, what is the "correct" way to create a member pointer to the base class's variable.
Ex.

```
class A
{
    int x;
    A():x(1){}
};
class B : public A
{
    int x;
    B():x(2){}
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    B classB;
    int B::*ptr = &B::x;
    int B::*ptr1 = &B::A::x;
    int A::*ptr2 = &A::x;
    printf("%d,%d,%d\n", classB.*ptr, classB.*ptr1, classB.*ptr2); 
    return 0;
}
```

On my compiler (LLVM GCC) this will print 2,1,1 like I would expect it to. This leads me to my two questions.

1. Are all three of the above implementations "safe" when it comes to the c++ standard?
2. And If so, Do any mainstream compilers have incompatibilities with either of these?

Comment: Why don't you leave int x out of class B?
Can you explain why you need int x in both class A and class B?

Comment: Above is a simplified example, but this is for a serialization/reflection system, and I have to make sure that it will remain as bug free as possible for any type of hierarchy, that gets passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *believe* all three are safe, although I can't cite chapter and verse from the standard on them. :)

That said, I have run across one very specific bug in member function pointers on an older version of Visual Studio (I don't remember which, I'm afraid). Specifically, I had a structure like this:

```
struct optable_entry {
    const char *name;
    void (*MyClass::run)();
};

const optable_entry operations[] = {
    { "foo", &MyClass::foo },
    /* ... */
};
```

With this, for some reason, the member function values would not be properly initialized. In my case, this was generated code, so it wasn't too much trouble to replace it with a massive switch statement instead, but it's something to watch out for - member function pointers are rarely enough used that weird corner cases like this may be lurking in your compiler.